# SSH authentication not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: openssh

SSH on my remote Ubuntu 18 server is rejecting all codes generated the Android Google authenticator. The mobile app is properly synched.

Answer (score 0):

The server's ssh supports password and secret key login,What do you mean by Android Google authenticator?